# crontab seems to run in syslog but no output is received (ubuntu)

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-20.04

I am using a virtualbox with ubuntu 20.04. Within the VM I have a condo environment and installed python-crontab using:

```
conda install -c conda-forge python-crontab
```

I want to continuously run a certain python file which will write to a database. I can make this happen when using job.run() but not when the job is actually on a time schedule.

I have tried the following things:

```
crontab -e
```

then adding in

```
 * * * * * python /home/cron/... to my python file
```

I have also tried:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

then adding in

```
 * * * * * python /home/cron/... to my python file
```

as well as just making a call to python and running the following:

```
from crontab import CronTab
cron = CronTab(user=True) 
job = cron.new(command='python /home/cron/... to my python file')
job.minute.every(1)
cron.write()
```

user=True I have also tried replacing by user=cron

Now as mentioned I can run job.run() and have new entries in my database. But when it is on a schedule nothing gets written to my database anymore.

My syslog file says the following:

```
(cron) CMD (python /home/cron/... to my python file)
(CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
(root) CDM (python /home/cron/... to my python file)
```

These messages do get written every minute, so cron does seem to run, why do I not see any output in my database then?

ps with some digging on the internet, I was told that the info message shouldn't interfere with the cron job itself

Comment: after some more testing, and writing a cronjob to a log file it seems that it cannot find python when ran as a cronjob. No clue what to do about this. I can however, run python in the terminal just fine

Comment: python can be added by adding /usr/bin/python3.8 to the cronjob, however, then it cannot find mysql